# How to use Creative Commons licensed videos on YouTube?

Tags: editing, youtube

According to [YouTube help center](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797468?hl=en), Creative Commons licensed videos can be reused and edit. 
But it is not allowed to download videos from YouTube, so how can i edit it?

YouTube Studio beta only allows to edit your uploaded videos.

Answer (score 1):

As Dr Mayhem mentioned, if you can see it and it has an appropriate license, you are allowed to reuse it.

I would recommend also as they suggested to ask the author first if they can send you a copy somehow. Alternately, I think [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) should have you covered for downloading directly. It's a command-line tool so you will have to use the shell of your OS (e.g. Command Prompt in Windows) to use it, but it's fairly easy to use and has a plethora of options for getting the exact quality you require. Generally you can probably get by with just calling it without any parameters e.g.:

> youtube-dl www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx

Comment: Is Youtube DL officia,l release b y youtube?

Comment: @DheerajMPai no.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see video, it is possible to reuse it - there are various applications that will let you use YouTube video, or you could record the screen using a camera, or your mobile phone etc.

Or you could ask the author.

There are many possibilities.